# send udp with python client and not receiving in nc

Tags: python, udp, netcat

I built a simple udp client in python to send data. To check it, i ran netcat to see if the data is received. This is my Python client:

```
def _send(self):
        data = {
           "key": "val"
        }
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        print 'sending %s to 127.0.01:9000' % json.dumps(data)
        sent = sock.sendto(json.dumps(data), ('127.0.0.1', 9000))
        print 'sent: %s' % sent
        sock.close()
```

I opened netcat like this `nc -l 127.0.0.1 9000`
With ipython icalled my client and the output was this:

```
sending {"key": "val"} to 127.0.0.1:9000
sent: 14
```

but there was no output from the netcat listener.
I tried to send data with netcat also like so

```
nc 127.0.0.1 9000
hello
```

and i received the data from the nc listener. 
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: `nc -u -l 127.0.0.1 9000`, where `-u` stands for udp mode in netcat

Comment: Well that did the work. Thanks :)
i ran `nc -u -l 127.0.0.1 9000` and i received the data